# iAd UITableViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I'm trying to implement iAd with a `UITableViewController`, but I can't figure out how to get the iAd banner to be at the bottom of the `UITableViewController`.

I can only find tutorials/info about iAd in Swift on `UIViewController`, and the stuff I found about iAd on `UITableViewController` is in Objective-C.

It has to be in Swift and the `UITableViewController` has to be in a Swift class, not Objective-C. I've tried all different types of Swift iAd tutorials but none have worked with `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Its should not matter what type of a controller it is as long as the you link and import iAd framework.

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

This code should display the ads. take a look at this example [iOS app as a money making machine using iAd app monetization technique](http://shrikar.com/blog/2014/12/06/ios-app-as-a-money-making-machine-using-iad-app-monetization-technique/)